# How to solve 'The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

May be I am going to apply too odd procedure in my project. Like I have 3 models named `RoleViewModel`, `ModuleModel` and `ModuleFunctionModel` and their relationship in `Entity framework` is like

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public int  RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleText { get; set; }
    public virtual  List<ModuleModel> Modules { get; set; }
}

[Table("Module")]
public class ModuleModel
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ModuleFunctionModel> ModuleFunctions { get; set; }

}
[Table("ModuleFunction")]
public class ModuleFunctionModel
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string FunctionName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModuleId")]
    public virtual ModuleModel Module { get; set; }
}
```

I have Multiple `Module` and this modules have separate multiple `ModuleFunctions` and all this Module are belongs to a `RoleViewModel`. My problem is when I am going to peek up all `Modules` it is not capable of sending the data of it's inner relationship. Sometimes it's sending data when I am in debugging mode and it's sending the data pretty well.

What I have noticed that when I am debugging line by line then it's capable of holding data in list of `ModuleFunctionModel` otherwise not. It's coming with a exception like this types of exceptions.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333620/the-entity-or-complex-type-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105377/error-the-entity-or-complex-type-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-qu), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215354/error-the-entity-or-complex-type-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-qu), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541671/c-sharp-the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no-longer-be-used). I have gone through their solution. But did not find a way to solve.

I have tried by this code

```
public new RoleViewModel Get(long id)
{
    using (var eLearningDBContext = new ELearningDBContext())
    {
        RoleViewModel roleViewModel = new RoleViewModel();
        roleViewModel.RoleId = roleContext.Where(m => m.RoleId == id).Select(r => r.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();
        roleViewModel.RoleText = roleContext.Where(m => m.RoleId == id).Select(r => r.RoleText).FirstOrDefault();
        var xx = eLearningDBContext.Modules.Select(m => m.ModuleFunctions);

        List<ModuleModel> query = (from m in eLearningDBContext.Modules select new ModuleModel
        {
            Id = m.Id,
            ModuleFunctions = m.ModuleFunctions.Select(s=> new ModuleFunctionModel
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                FunctionName = s.FunctionName
            }).AsQueryable().ToList(),

        }).AsQueryable().ToList();


        roleViewModel.Modules = query.ToList();
        return roleViewModel;
    }
}
```

I have also tried this way but no desired result. But alas I am undone. Could you please help me.

```
RoleViewModel roleViewModel = new RoleViewModel();
roleViewModel.RoleId = roleContext.Where(m => m.RoleId == id).Select(r => r.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();
roleViewModel.RoleText = roleContext.Where(m => m.RoleId == id).Select(r => r.RoleText).FirstOrDefault();
roleViewModel.Modules= eLearningDBContext.Modules.ToList();
return roleViewModel;
```

**Update**

[image: Step1]

[image: Step2]

[image: Step 3]
Here I have attached my screenshot. I getting problem from the inner model named `ModuleFunctionModel`. Except this everything is fine. Neither of the suggested solution were helpful.

Comment: Why are you doing `.AsQueryable().ToList()` here? That's completely pointless.

Comment: @lazycoder - Have you tried the solutions suggested by the questions you saw?..

Comment: It's does not work if I don't use this.

Comment: @GiladGreen, yeah. I had. It's did not work. Moreover i have 2 inner `List`. they have 1. I am not pretty sure here is my problem is?

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use `new ModuleModel` and `new ModuleFunctionModel` inside LINQ to Entities query because `ModuleModel` and `ModuleFunctionModel` are **entity classes**. As the links suggest, create special classes `ModuleViewModel` and `ModuleFunctionViewModel`.

Comment: @IvanStoev I got it. But what about the second code? Possibly here nothing is wrong.

Comment: @lazycoder - what is the problem with the second code? And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The second code should work. If you have problem with lazy loading, you could always use eager loading, e.g. `roleViewModel.Modules= eLearningDBContext.Modules.Include(e => e.ModuleFunctions).ToList();`

Comment: @IvanStoev Could you please use a moment on my update.

Comment: @GiladGreen I have used the second code and I got this problem in the screenshot. Could you please identify where the problem is.

Comment: So the issue is with lazy loading. Not sure what the last screenshot shows, the `Include` should have fixed the issue, why it's shown in red?

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve in your example code. - Can you reproduce this without having such an "abstract" data model? Like with with a different model (e.g. Employees, Departments, Managers etc.).

Comment: @IvanStoev Probably I have got my solution. It's exactly due to lazy loading . I am going to give an answer of my own question as I got a solution by myself. One more thing `Include` may violate the rules of `lazyloading` So personally I don't like the way but probably it will solve the issue.